# Session variable are empty in specific pages

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am saving logged in users in the session.It is visible in some pages and some pages sesssion is empty

When I print `$_SESSION` it is showing only id on some page

```
Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1588162137 )
```

I added debug_backtrace . Session variable are showing in on one page and not on other pages

```
 ["session"]=>
  object(CI_Session)#16 (4) {
    ["userdata"]=>
    &array(29) {
      ["__ci_last_regenerate"]=>
      int(1588234145)
      ["SESS_USERID"]=>
      string(4) "7506"


["session"]=>
  object(CI_Session)#16 (4) {
    ["userdata"]=>
    &array(1) {
      ["__ci_last_regenerate"]=>
      int(1588234345)
    }
    ["_driver":protected]=>
    string(5) "files"
```

Comment: Do you use `session_start()` on every page ?

Comment: Yes I load the library session

Comment: it is some pages it is empty

Comment: On some page it is printing

Comment: Is your version of CodeIgnitier up to date ?

Comment: How do you set sessions ?

Comment: I set  like $this->session->userdata('INSTAC_YR');

Comment: I am usign version 3.1.11

Comment: I added debug_backtrace. It is showing session variables on one page and not on other pages

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: 3.1.11 version i am using

Comment: Issue is resolved after adding ob_start() at the start of the index.php page